# Preg_replace() ==> SPAN id="2015-03-09" class="five"

Tags: html, php

> `<?php
> $id = preg_quote('2015-03-09');
> $newData = preg_replace('#(id="' . $id . '"\s*>\s*)(.+)(\s*</\s*span>)#', '${1}123$3', $data);
> ?>`

ИТОГ --> `<span id="2015-03-09">123</span>`

А подскажите, пожалуйста, что написать в `preg_replace()`, чтобы итог был вот такой: `<span id="2015-03-09" class="five">123</span>` ? Т.е. добавить атрибут "class". Просто в этих символах `'#(id="' . $id . '"\s*>\s*)(.+)(\s*</\s*span>)#'` я не разбираюсь)

Comment: А $data = ?

Comment: Да это так, содержимое файла fopen() и file_get_contents(). Не обращайте внимания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такое подозрение, что это я кому-то уже написал эту регулярку...
Если особо не мудрить, то можно так:

```
<?
$id = preg_quote('2015-03-09');
$newData = preg_replace('#(id="' . $id . '")(\s*)(\s*.*\s*>\s*)(.*)(\s*</\s*span>)#', '${1} class="five"${3}123$5', $data);
```

Comment: Да, Вы это мне писали. У меня по этой регулярке возник вопрос. И вот я получил ответ. Спасибо.